# Limit the pagination in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, pagination

I've built a custom pagination with this directive:

```
app.directive('postsGenreLink', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'posts-genre-link.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$routeParams', function($scope, $element, $routeParams) {
            var currentGenrePage = (!$routeParams.page) ? 1 : parseInt($routeParams.page),
                linkPrefix = (!$routeParams.slug) ? 'page/' : 'genre/' + $routeParams.slug + '/page/';

            $scope.postsGenreLink = {
                prevLink: linkPrefix + (currentGenrePage - 1),
                hopLink: linkPrefix,
                nextLink: linkPrefix + (currentGenrePage + 1),
                sep: (!$element.attr('sep')) ? '|' : $element.attr('sep'),
                prevLabel: (!$element.attr('prev-label')) ? 'Previous Page' : $element.attr('prev-label'),
                nextLabel: (!$element.attr('next-label')) ? 'Next Page' : $element.attr('next-label'),
                hopLabel: (!$element.attr('Jump')) ? 'Jump' : $element.attr('Jump')
            };
        }]
    };
});
```

This is my `posts-genre-link.html`:

```
<nav aria-label="...">
  <ul class="pagination pt-3">
    <li class="page-item" ng-class="{'disabled' : currentGenrePage == 1}">
      <a class="page-link" href="{{postsGenreLink.prevLink}}">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="i in [].constructor(totalPages) track by $index" class="page-item" ng-class="{'active' : currentGenrePage == $index + 1}"><a class="page-link" href="{{postsGenreLink.hopLink+($index + 1)}}">{{$index + 1}}</a></li>

    <li class="page-item" ng-class="{'disabled' : currentGenrePage >= totalPages}">
      <a class="page-link" href="{{postsGenreLink.nextLink}}">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The `totalPages` is a scope variable defined in the controller `$scope.totalPages = parseInt(headers('X-WP-TotalPages'));` and it basically contains the number of the pages.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

My problem is when this value is very high; I don't want to display 200-300 pages, I would like to display only the `currentGenrePage` and 2 pages behind and forward with the classic dots to underline that there are more pages. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved "graphically" (hiding the number if the current page plus 1 is lower then the `$index` or current Page less 3 higher than the `$index`.

```
<nav aria-label="...">
  <ul class="pagination pt-3">
    <li class="page-item" ng-class="{'disabled' : currentGenrePage == 1}">
      <a class="page-link" href="{{postsGenreLink.prevLink}}">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item disabled" ng-class="{'notshow' : currentGenrePage == 1 || currentGenrePage == 2 || currentGenrePage == 3}">
      <a class="page-link" href="">...</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="i in [].constructor(totalPages) track by $index" class="page-item" ng-class="{'active' : currentGenrePage == $index + 1, 'notshow' :  currentGenrePage + 1 < $index || currentGenrePage - 3 > $index}"><a class="page-link" href="{{postsGenreLink.hopLink+($index + 1)}}">{{$index + 1}}</a></li>
    <li class="page-item disabled" ng-class="{'notshow' : currentGenrePage == totalPages || currentGenrePage == totalPages -1 || currentGenrePage == totalPages - 2}">
      <a class="page-link" href="">...</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item" ng-class="{'disabled' : currentGenrePage >= totalPages}">
      <a class="page-link" href="{{postsGenreLink.nextLink}}">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

where:

```
.notshow {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I did try something like this at first, the issues I see right now are when the first page is still in view say you have page 2 selected it shouldn't be showing the ... before the 1, the other issue here is the pagination control will change size when you're at the beginning or end of the list vs in the middle.  If you do the logic in JS you can account for these things, but if it covers the use cases you need then this is definitely the simpler option.

Comment: You are right, I've fixed this adding to initial dots: `|| currentGenrePage == 2 || currentGenrePage == 3` and to final dots `|| currentGenrePage == totalPages -1 || currentGenrePage == totalPages - 2`, since the pagination works with 2 number before and after the currentPage.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start with something relatively simple I wrote a pagination directive here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/W85f8IYXHLNmVkmm?p=preview

```
.directive('pagingDisplay', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        startAt: '=', //Two way binding for which element to start at
        numPerPage: '@', //Number of elements we want per page
        totalElements: '@', //Total number of elements in the collection
        maxButtons: '@' //Maximum number of page number buttons to show
      },
      templateUrl: 'templateId.html',
      link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
        //Computed when the num per page and total are provided
        var _totalPages = 0;

        //Max page buttons to show (default 5)
        var _maxPages = 5;
        scope.model = {
          selectedPage: 0,
          showForward: false,
          showBackward: true
        };

        /**
         * Uses the current selected page, num pages, and max pages to
         * create an array that corresponds to the page numbers shown
         */
        function genPagesArray(numPages) {
          scope.pages = [];

          if (numPages <= _maxPages) {
            for (var i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
              scope.pages.push(i);
            }
          } else {
            var showEndPage = true,
              showStartPage = true;
            var halfPages = Math.floor((_maxPages - 1) / 2);

            var firstPage = Math.max(0, scope.model.selectedPage - halfPages);
            var lastPage = firstPage + _maxPages;

            if (lastPage > _totalPages) {

              firstPage += (_totalPages - lastPage);
              lastPage = _totalPages;
            }

            for (var i = firstPage, x = 0; i < lastPage && x < _maxPages; x++, i++) {
              scope.pages.push(i)

              if (i == numPages - 1)
                showEndPage = false;
              if (i == 0)
                showStartPage = false;
            }

            if (showEndPage) {
              scope.pages.pop();
              scope.pages.push(numPages - 1);
            }
            if (showStartPage) {
              scope.pages.shift();
              scope.pages.unshift(0);
            }
          }
        }
        genPagesArray(5);

        scope.$watch('totalElements', function(newVal) {
          var intVal = scope.totalElements;
          if (intVal && !isNaN(intVal = parseInt(intVal))) {
            _totalPages = Math.ceil(intVal / scope.numPerPage)
            if (scope.model.selectedPage > _totalPages) {
              scope.firstPage();
            } else {
              genPagesArray(_totalPages);
            }
          }
        });

        scope.$watch('maxButtons', function(newVal) {
          var intVal = scope.maxButtons;
          if (intVal && !isNaN(intVal = parseInt(intVal))) {
            _maxPages = intVal;
            genPagesArray(_totalPages);
          }
        });

        scope.prevPage = function() {
          if (scope.model.selectedPage > 0)
            scope.changeSelectedPage(scope.model.selectedPage - 1)
        }
        scope.nextPage = function() {
          if (scope.model.selectedPage < _totalPages - 1)
            scope.changeSelectedPage(scope.model.selectedPage + 1)
        }
        scope.lastPage = function() {
          scope.changeSelectedPage(_totalPages - 1)
        }
        scope.firstPage = function() {
          scope.changeSelectedPage(0)
        }

        scope.changeSelectedPage = function(pageToSelect) {
          scope.model.selectedPage = pageToSelect;
          scope.startAt = pageToSelect * parseInt(scope.numPerPage);
          genPagesArray(_totalPages)
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

The directive template

```
<div>
    <span class="pagination-button" ng-click="firstPage()"> |< </span><span class="pagination-button" ng-click="prevPage()"> << </span><span class="pagination-button" ng-click="changeSelectedPage(page)" ng-class="{'selected':model.selectedPage == page}"
      ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index">
    {{(page+1)}}
  </span><span class="pagination-button" ng-click="nextPage()"> >> </span><span class="pagination-button" ng-click="lastPage()"> >| </span>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.pagination-button {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 2px;
  /* Disable Text Selection */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

.pagination-button:hover {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination-button:active,
.pagination-button.selected {
  background-color: #ccffaa;
}
```

Usage

```
  <paging-display num-per-page="5" max-buttons="{{myctrl.maxPageButtons}}" total-elements="{{myctrl.filtered.length}}" start-at="myctrl.startAt">
  </paging-display>
```

If you want something a bit more robust tested/widely used there is also a pagination directive in ui-bootstrap.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Hi @shaunhusain, I already set up the pagination to suits my directive and all, I would like to modify mine in order to get the expected behaviour. Maybe I can add a filter in the ng-repeat and look if the $index is different from the currentPage +/- 2, don’t display it.

Comment: You can certainly try some other means of getting this done but if you want to have first/last buttons that optionally show up etc. like you see on most pagination components then it's more complex then I think you can handle in a couple of filters.  Basically the "genPagesArray" function is where all the logic is happening to decide which things need to display based on the total num of elements, elements per page, max buttons to display etc. so it will be hard to capture all of that in a couple of filters.  Everything else in my code is just handlers or watchers.

Comment: @GoingSolo also if you want to just copy mine and clean it up I'd appreciate any feedback/updates to it, was planning to post this on my site as an example for a blog post, so changes are welcome.

Comment: Well, the first and last button are not necessary, but they can be hardcoded: the first page is always 1, the last Pages is always equal to the total Pages. I can add something like this in the repeat: ng-class=“{‘notshow’ : $index + 2 == currentPages || $index - 2 == currentPages}” where .notshow{display:none;}

Comment: Yah I initially tried something simpler like your suggesting but the display would shift in terms of number of elements shown when you're at the beginning or end of a list of pages, give it a shot.

Comment: I solved adding {'notshow' :  currentGenrePage + 1 < $index || currentGenrePage - 3 > $index} and then adding some dots before and at the end and display them if {'notshow' : currentGenrePage == 1} or {'notshow' : currentGenrePage == totalPages}.

Comment: Post as an answer would like to see how it works and if it works with different numbers of elements and max page sizes specified.

Comment: I admit it's a simple solution, maybe not the best way tho... code below.

Comment: "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler." -Einstein... no worries simpler the better if it does the job :)

Comment: You can see the code working here: https://new.wearegoingsolo.com/genre/all